# How to print the System.out.println logs for junit while running maven build using jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, logging, junit

I need to get the `System.out.println()` logs in Jenkins for JUnit and as well as the logs for the methods which are getting called from JUnit (version 4.8.2)

```
@Test
public void junitTestMethod() {

  anotherMethod();// how to print sop logs for this method
  System.out.println("How to print these system.out.printn logs");
  Assert.assertEquals(true,"True");
}
```

Please suggest how we can achieve the same.

Comment: Please provide a bit more info. What Junit version do you use? What's your launcher (maven plugin, main method, something else)?

Comment: Hello @Dubilyer - I am using JUnit version 4.8.2 and launcher is maven plugin.
I am expecting these logs to be printed in jenkins console when my JUnit test cases are executing while building of application using maven.

Answer (score 0):

You need a framework that does this for you.
Sprint AOP can be used in this case. Or you have to create your own framework/Design that calls method.

Selenium and CompleteTest can also be used to print the details but they are for Automation. I'm hoping this is not related to you.

Comment: I am trying to do this in an application which is based on core java . 
But even i am not sure how Spring AOP can be helpful here. Isn't there any way to achieve this using some maven configuration or by doing configuration at jenkins end.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is migrating to logger (log4j, java.util.logging e.t.c).

If there's a reason for using both logger and stdout, change System.out to custom stream for example in BeforeClass.

Something like:

```
System.setOut(new PrintStream(System.out) {
  public void println(String s) {
    logger.log("[system.out] " + s);
    super.println(s);
  }
});
```

After that every call of system.out.printeln will produce a log entry and then print to stdout.

Comment: hello @Dubilyer - I already tried adding logs using log4j or using java logging api.
But in that case these logs gets printed only while running test (by using option run as JUnit) case in IDE . While building application using maven (mvn clean install)  these logs are skipped.

Comment: Check your logging level. I log4j a lot and it prints logs during the maven build. Take a look on https://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_logging_levels.htm .

Comment: I already tried changing the log level and even log statement with fatal levels are also not getting printed.